# SSRS non-grouped data in the middle of grouped data in table

Tags: reporting-services

I'm not sure if I worded this properly.  It's a lot easier to show.  So without doing a subreport, is there any way to have the non-grouped data inside of grouped data.

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║     Cars     ║ Name         ║    Date    ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ 2011 Chevy   ║ John D       ║ 1/1/2013   ║
║    ║ 2012 Ford    ║              ║            ║
║  2 ║ 2010 Pontiac ║ Jane D       ║ 1/1/2012   ║
║  3 ║ 1969 Chevy   ║ Bob H        ║ 12/1/2011  ║
║    ║ 1930 Ford    ║              ║            ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Cars is not grouped. So there is 1:N relationship there with all the other data.

What I know you can do and have done is have the "Cars" all the way to the right and have it be ID, Name, Date, Cars but I cant seem how to get the cars in the middle of all of the grouped data columns.   I know a subreport is "possible" but wondered if I am just missing the obvious

Comment: You could consider changing your SQL so that it produces one row per "group", and either concatenate the Cars column, or have a Car1 and Car2 column that get concatenated in the report.

Comment: @reindeerKurt How do you know Car "2012 Ford" is the part of or group of   "2011 Chevy" ?  if you have that value then you can include that as a column in your DataSet and Add Row group using "Column"

Comment: Are the 2011 Chevy and 2012 Ford both owned by John D? So you want to display the owner only once but list all the cars?

Comment: @Tab It is an option to group the cars together but that SQL always seems slow

Comment: The grouping and stuff isn't so much the problem as the placement of the column.  I can get everything displayed and grouped fine but I just want the column inside all of the non-grouped columns.   Hard to explain.  I'm sure I'm just using the wrong verbage

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack, but I do it all the time:

You can embed a table in the Cars cell. You just need 1 Details cell on your embedded table (get rid of the headers and the extra columns that are auto added), and have it list your cars.  It will only list the cars that are related to the value in column 1 on each row of the parent table, and should probably end up looking like your example above.